# Im trying to make an animation script in GameMaker

Tags: animation, game-maker

In the script its supposed to run the animation line 6-8 currently and then its supposed to see if down is not pressed and the direction is down then set the sprite to look down Line 23-25 but it keeps playing the animation
`x = PlayerObject.x;
y = PlayerObject.y;

```
Direction = "";

if (keyboard_check(vk_down)) {
    Direction = "Down";
    sprite_index = CaseyDownWalk;

}
 else if (keyboard_check(vk_right)) {
    Direction = "Right";
    sprite_index = CaseyRight;
}
else if (keyboard_check(vk_up)) {
    Direction = "Up";
    sprite_index = CaseyUp;
}
else if (keyboard_check(vk_left)) {
    Direction = "Left";
    sprite_index = CaseyLeft;
}
if not (keyboard_check(vk_down)) { 
if (Direction == "Down") {
sprite_index = CaseyDown;
    
    
    
    }
}
```

`i tried changing up the code and what its supposed to do is to play the walking animation then repeat until key not pressed then set the animation to stop`

Comment: Not sure what you mean with `x = PlayerObject.x; y = PlayerObject.y`, since that's not defined in your code snippet. But have you tried setting `image_speed` to 0 when it should stop walking (and back to 1 when you start walking)

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet, the line where it says `sprite_index = CaseyDown;` will never be executed.

In the beginning, you set `Direction = ""`. When the down button is released (and no other button pressed) it will thus still be `Direction = ""`, and the condition `if (Direction == "Down")` can't be true.

An alternative would be the following: Instead of the direction, you check if you are NOT moving. Then you check which button was released using  `if keyboard_check_released(vk_down)`:

```
moving = false;

if (keyboard_check(vk_down)) {
    moving = true;    
    sprite_index = CaseyDownWalk;
}
 else if (keyboard_check(vk_right)) {
    moving = true;    
    sprite_index = CaseyRight;
}
else if (keyboard_check(vk_up)) {
    moving = true;    
    sprite_index = CaseyUp;
}
else if (keyboard_check(vk_left)) {
    moving = true;    
    sprite_index = CaseyLeft;
}

if (not moving) { 
     if (keyboard_check_released(vk_down)) {
          sprite_index = CaseyDown;   
    }
}
```